# How can I run Java program on the remote EC2 using AWS SDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am new to EC2 and AWS SDK . I want to execute java program on my EC2 instance from AWS SDK or using java API for EC2. which method i should used ? and how ? Also how can i run commands on EC2 instance using same API.

I am stuck at this , any help will be highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can do it on instance startup via  [ec2-run-instances](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/CommandLineReference/ApiReference-cmd-RunInstances.html)
arguments: user-data or user-data-file

Amazon Linux and Ubuntu AMIs have [CloudInit](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CloudInit) - it calls script passed as user-data at instance initialization

for CLI it will look like

```
ec2-run-instances --key [KEYPAIR] --user-data-file [script_file] ami-[your-ami]
```

script_file could look something like

```
#! /bin/bash
cd path-to-you-program  
java -cp....
```

Answer (score -1):

As far as I understand, you have a ec2 instance setup that has a java program in it. For running a java program on your ec2 you do not need aws sdk. And for that matter of fact to run any command on your ec2 all you need to do is ssh to your machine and then execute commands from the console(if your instance is linux) and for windows use remote desktop to connect to your instance. 

The AWS SDK is used for configuring and managing your ec2 instances( for tasks like bringing up a new instance or terminating it, specifying configurations etc)